# Are all analytic continuations consistent with $1+2+3+\dots=-\frac{1}{12}$?

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta, divergent-series, analytic-continuation

**Background:**

One way to "prove" that $1+2+3+\dots=-\frac{1}{12}$ is to define the function $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}$ for $z\in\mathbb C, \operatorname{Re}(z)>1,$ then define $\zeta(z)$ as the analytic continuation of $f$ to all of $\mathbb C$, and then show that $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$. Naively replacing the terms in the sum defining $f$ with $z=-1$ suggests that $1+2+3+\dots=-\frac{1}{12}$.

I am curious whether this general idea could be used to rigorously define sums of divergent series. Given a formal series such as $1+2+3+\dots$, could one define the sum to be the analytic continuation of *any* function definable somewhere in $\mathbb C$ using a summation formula that reproduces this sum somewhere else? Would such a definition lead to a unique answer?

**Question:**

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a family of functions $a_n:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C,z\mapsto a_n(z)$ such that:

1. $a_n(z_0)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and for some $z_0\in\mathbb C$,
2. $f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z)$ is well defined on some open subset $A\subset\mathbb C$.

Let $g$ be the analytic continuation of $f$ to the rest of $\mathbb C$. Must $g(z_0)=-\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: @WiilG Deleted my comment while you were typing yours. Sorry.

Comment: Borel-Laplace summation is a little related, which gives a mechanical way to associate one analytic function

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426993/is-the-sum-of-all-natural-numbers-unique?rq=1 for a counterexample.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thanks, so the answer to my question "must $g(z_0)=-1/12$ is a definite "no."

Comment: Yes. It would seem so.

Comment: Closing as duplicate. Will ask another question about whether this is true of "better behaved" divergent sums like $1+2+4+\dots$, which satisfies nicer algebraic properties.